# Istio routing unique URL to specific pod

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am interested in using Istio in a use case where I spin up a pod based on some event (user starting a game for example), and allow that user to connect to the specific pod through a unqiue URL. Then when this game is over, I can spin the pod down.

I am trying to configure Istio in such a way that either the subdomain or URL can indicate a specific pod to send that request.

Maybe some way to dynamically control label matching? Like `<pod_label>.api.com` routes to pod matching label `label_name: <pod_label>` without having to update VirtualServices and DestinationRoutes every time a pod is created?

Edit:

A psuedo config would look similar to:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: dynamic-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - r.prod.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
      uri:
        prefix: "/pod/{pod_name}"
      ignoreUriCase: true
    route:
    - destination:
        host: {pod_name}.prod.svc.cluster.local
```

(not sure if this would belong in the virtual service or the destination route)

Comment: Did you try anything, any configuratio or you just looking for idea? You want to use specific Istio version? How would you configure this `event catch`, some kubernetes resources, some specific app? Istio can match by [conditions](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#routing-rules).

Comment: @PjoterS I'm familiar with the match conditions, but based on the documentation it seems like it only works if I know the exact value of the tag I am looking for, or if I use `*` I'd have to route all to a random pod in a service.
Edit: the solution now seems to be to dynamically generate virtualservices or destination rules pointing to specific pods, but that doesn't feel like an optimal solution. Also I am looking at the most recent version of Istio

Comment: Not the exact value of the tag, the exact pod rather.

Comment: I've updated the question to show an example of what I am looking for configuration wise

Comment: @danthegoodman Did you every figure this out?

Comment: @DaveNew No, I ended up going with another solution. Would love to figure it out with either Istio or Consul though.

Comment: @danthegoodman thanks for the reply. Were you able to achieve "pod-specific" routing in the end?  Please do share your solution :)

Comment: Sorry, we ended using another method entirely. No longer did pod specific routing